# Expand 3-level hierarchic arrays to 10 levels, struggling with how

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

I'm trying to make an HTML form with 10 dropdown menus, where all menus contains hierarchical dynamical options; meaning the contents of each dropdown menu depends dynamically on the selection in the previous dropdown.

I've managed to make 3 levels of the above mentioned so far, but I'm really struggling with how to expand it further, up to 10 levels.

My problem seems to be how to combine the nested arrays - who are storing the menu options - into supporting 10 levels with how to get each ".onchange" functions to read through the arrays right.
Perhaps the reason why I am struggling is that I'm at the top of my JS capabilities here, or perhaps I picked a bad strategy for the task. Don't hesitate to tell me so, if so.

This is where I am so far, would really appreciate input to unstuck myself:

```
<html>
<head>
   <style>
      #second, #third {
         display: none;
      }
   </style>

   <script>
      var subjectObject = {
         "1st select A": {
            "2nd select A": ["3rd select A", "3rd select B", "3rd select C", "3rd select D"],
            "2nd select B": ["3rd select A", "3rd select D"],
            "2nd select C": ['3rd select D', '3rd select E'],
            "2nd select D": ["3rd select A", "3rd select B", "3rd select D"]
         },
         "1st select B": {
            "2nd select F": ['3rd select B', '3rd select C', '3rd select G'],
            "2nd select G": ['3rd select C', '3rd select G', '3rd select H']
         },
         "1st select C": {
            "2nd select G": ['3rd select A', '3rd select B', '3rd select G'],
            "2nD select H": ['3rd select C', '3rd select D', '3rd select E'],
         },
         "1st select D": {
            "2nd select I": ['3rd select D', '3rd select E', '3rd select F'],
            "2nd select J": ['3rd select F', '3rd select G'],
            "2nd select K": []
         }
      }

// onload 1st level below -----------

      window.onload = function () {
         var first = document.getElementById('first')
         var second = document.getElementById('second')
         var third = document.getElementById('third')

         for (var x in subjectObject) {
            // console.log(x);
            first.options[first.options.length] = new Option(x)
         }

 // onchange 2nd level below -----------

         first.onchange = function () {
            second.length = 1
            third.length = 1

            second.style.display = 'block'
            third.style.display = 'none'

            for (var y in subjectObject[this.value]) {
               // console.log(y);
               second.options[second.options.length] = new Option(y)
            }
         }

// onchange 3rd level below -----------

         second.onchange = function () {
            third.length = 1

            third.style.display = 'block'
            z = subjectObject[first.value][this.value]
            console.log(z);
            for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
               third.options[third.options.length] = new Option(z[i])
            }
         }
      }
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <select id="first">
      <option value=""> Select Option </option>
   </select>

   <select id="second">
      <option value=""> Select Option </option>
   </select>

   <select id="third">
      <option value=""> Select Option </option>
   </select>
   <!-- Continue with more below -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. This does look a bit weird... SQL would likely help you out quite a bit. can you have this data within a database of any kind?  What is the nature of these drop down boxes? Like, are you trying to narrow down a list of options?  Additional context would help a lot.

Comment: @This Guy: Hi. The reason for HTML/JS is for max compatibility, all in 1 document. Prefer this over database (requires dependencies), though db is probably a smarter idea. :)
The dropboxes are for a file labelling model. Kindof like "Original document - revision1 - edit B - for further review.docx". That's 4 levels, if you know how I mean. Yes, narrowing down a list of options, however some options needs to be available for more than 1 above category. So it's not as simple as straight tree-structure.
What looks weird about it, plz?

Comment: OK. how about this, if all 10 options are required..: create a dataset and then query it to provide list options: like { option: 'final selection A', 1:'first option A', 2:'second option A', ... 10:'tenth option A'}, {option:'final selection B', 1:'first option A', 2:'second option A', ... 10:'tenth option B'} - you need to have all of your records for the final selection defined in a standard way. then you can query those records for ones which match the existing drop downs. I highly recommend making a map, listing the final options that you need... start at the end and work backwards.

Comment: @This Guy. Thanks for suggesting. This may look a little weird because I'm not fluent in JS. This is borderline beyond my top JS level, so .. 
Querying the arrays is actually what I'm doing above, using .OnChange. Then isolate the array below a certain level, using currently selected word as key. 
I just can't figure out how to expand the number of levels beyond the existing 3. 
Mainly how to formulate the code correctly to query the array, but also to formulate the array for more than 3 levels. 
I believe it's possible this way, so I thought I would reach out.